# String concatenation with newline not working as expected

Tags: powershell

I want to add a line break without adding a whole 'nother line to do so, here be my code:

```
"-- MANIFEST COUNT -- " >> "C:\psTest\test1.txt"
$manCount = (Get-ChildItem -filter "*manifest.csv").Count 
$manCount + " `n" >> "C:\psTest\test1.txt"
```

I thought that `` + " `n" `` would tack a line break onto the count, but it's not doing anything.  I tried also `` + "`r`n" `` (I found this suggestion elsewhere on SO) but to no avail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me complement [your own solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42843680/45375) with an explanation:

Because `$manCount`, the LHS, is of type `[int]`,

```
$manCount + " `n"
```

is effectively the same as:

```
$manCount + [int] " `n".Trim()
```

or:

```
$manCount + [int] ""
```

which is effectively the same as:

```
$manCount + 0
```

and therefore a no-op.

In PowerShell, the type of the LHS of an expression typically<sup>[1]</sup>
 determines what type the RHS will be coerced to, if necessary.

Therefore, by casting `$manCount` to `[string]`, `+` then performs *string* concatenation, as you intended.

As [Matt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3829407/matt) points out in a comment on your answer, you can also use *string interpolation*:

```
"$manCount `n"
```

---

<sup>[1]There are exceptions; e.g., `'3' - '1'` yields `[int] 2`; i.e., PowerShell treats both operands as *numbers*, because operator `-` has no meaning in a *string* context.</sup>

Comment: I come from VB, where concat between a string and numeric will end up as a string or throw an error.  This returned the number without error and without line break, which was not intuitive for me.

Comment: @n8. I see. PowerShell's automatic type conversion is generally very helpful, but it does have its pitfalls.

Answer (score 1):

The integer needed to be cast as a string in order for the concatenation to take:

```
"-- MANIFEST COUNT -- " >> "C:\psTest\test1.txt"
$manCount = (Get-ChildItem -filter "*manifest.csv").Count 
[string]$manCount + "`r`n" >> "C:\psTest\test1.txt"
```

Comment: ``"$manCount `r`n"``  would also work. Using something like `Add-Content` cmdlet might help as well. If nothing else just for readability

Comment: Ah, I am unaccustomed to a variable from working within a string such as that.